# How to use perl regular expressions to parse a java file

Tags: regex, perl

I want to learn more about using regular expressions in perl to parse text by parsing a simple .java file to find out all the int, boolean, double, and string variables from it(no arrays) and putting those variables into their respective perl arrays. For example if there is a int variable in the .java file called 'x' perl inserts the string 'x' into an array that contains all the int variables, and so on for the doubles, booleans, and strings. While I can open files in perl and do basic pasing such as printing out the lines of text to the terminal unfortunately I don't really know how do anything more complicated which would involve the use of regular expressions

Here is what I wrote down so far in my perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print "enter the name of the java file you want to parse:\n";
my $javafile = <STDIN>;
chomp $javafile;
my @listofdubs=();
my @listofints=();
my @listofbools=();
my @listofstrings=();

open my $info, $javafile or die "Could not open $javafile: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>)  {   
    #print "$line\n"; 
}

close $info;
```

And here is a simple java file I cooked up that has a few int, boolean, double, and string variable decalred inside of it:

```
public class examplejava{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        int thing= 70;
        int boo = 31;
        boolean example3= false;
        String example1= "stack";
        String example2= "overflow";
        double example6= 4.32;
        boolean example4= true;
        double example5= 2.4349;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex is not suitable for this task. Briefly, a regex can't figure out nested structures like escaped strings etc to the full extent that a structured language permits and requires. Read up on parsers instead.

Answer (score 0):

While this is probably very hard in the general case, it's simple enough to do something with your sample data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @listofdubs    = ();
my @listofints    = ();
my @listofbools   = ();
my @listofstrings = ();

while (<>) {
  push @listofdubs,    $1 if /\bdouble\s+(\w+)/;
  push @listofints,    $1 if /\bint\s+(\w+)/;
  push @listofbools,   $1 if /\bboolean\s+(\w+)/;
  push @listofstrings, $1 if /\bString\s+(\w+)/;
}

print "@listofdubs\n";
```

(I've removed all the user-prompting stuff. Instead, this accepts a filename as a command-line argument.)